# Regex for numbers with optional decimal value, fixed to two positions?

Tags: objective-c, regex, nsregularexpression

I need to know if a string is in the following format:

1. Any number of integers followed by:
2. an optional group of:
3. a decimal followed by two digits (required if a decimal is provided)

This allows any number of digits, and I thought it was in the proper format to allow an optional group that consists of a period followed by two digits, but for some reason this doesn't allow the decimal. Perhaps the decimal isn't escaped appropriately?

```
@"^[0-9]+(\\.[0-9][0-9])?$"
```

I tried `@"^[0-9]+(\.[0-9][0-9])?$"` but Xcode throws a compile-time warning: `Unknown escape sequence \.`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest using `^[0-9]+(?:\\.[0-9]{2})?$` regex (in Objective C, we need to escape regex backslash).

- `^` - String start
- `[0-9]+` - Any number of digits
- `(?:\\.[0-9]{2})?` - Optional group:

  - `\\.` - A literal dot
  - `[0-9]{2}` - Exactly two digits
- `$` - String end

Here is a sample code you can use (it will report a match in this case):

```
NSString *pattern = @"^[0-9]+(?:\\.[0-9]{2})?$";
NSString *string = @"12345.20";
NSError *error = nil;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern options:0 error:&error];

NSRange textRange = NSMakeRange(0, string.length);
NSRange matchRange = [regex rangeOfFirstMatchInString:string options:NSMatchingReportProgress range:textRange];

// Did we find a matching range
if (matchRange.location != NSNotFound)
    NSLog (@"YES! It is matched!");
else
    NSLog (@"NO MATCH!");
```

Comment: This too doesn't allow you to input a '.' character - falls into your else statement.

Comment: Oh I see the problem. It does live validation and so inserting a single decimal does indeed not match the pattern. Your pattern is fine, it just won't work for live validation.

Comment: I see. I'd recommend to add such details as "live regex validation" to the question next time.